# Using Azure Data Factory to import a column of type NUMBER in oracle results in a strange precision error

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We're going from ORACLE to SQL in azure.

AFAIK we have to use pipelines and data sets, with a variety of COPY operations.

There does not seem to be a way to import the data from Oracle and manipulate it via Data Flows without putting it into a staging database first, and even then it would be too late for this issue.

The issue is that a column of type NUMBER in oracle might have a value of 1.1234 or 2.23423485

I set the SQL data type to DECIMAL(12, 8) which should cover all the scenarios with a COPY TABLE operation.

I've tried doing the copy as number, and even as varchar:

```
              {
                "source": {
                  "name": "MYDECIMALVALUE",
                  "type": "String"
                },
                "sink": {
                  "name": "MyDecimalValue",
                  "type": "String",
                  "physicalType": "varchar"
                }
              },
```

However the result for the above two numbers would be:

> 2.23423485 stays as 2.23423485

> 1.1234 becomes 1.12340001

Some strange precision issues pulling NUMBER out of oracle.

The same happens with the config above set to

```
              {
                "source": {
                  "name": "MYDECIMALVALUE",
                  "type": "Decimal"
                },
                "sink": {
                  "name": "MyDecimalValue",
                  "type": "Decimal",
                  "physicalType": "decimal",
                  "precision": 12,
                  "scale": 8,
                }
              },
```

Is there any way around this strange quirk?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to reproduce your scenario and also got similar result when we have Decimal(p,s) data type is already given in SQL table.

> DECIMAL(precision, scale)
>
> > `precision`  -- the maximum number of digits the decimal may store. Precision includes both left and right side of decimal point. It accepts values from 1 to 38. The default is 18.
> > `scale`  -- optional, specifies the number of digits after the decimal point. Scale must be between 0 up to the same value as the precision.

As your scenario scale his 8 and the number Geeting from Oracal has scale 4 so SQL is adding 4 zeros at the end of the number to get the required scale of data, like below image:

[image]

**Decimal has a fixed precision while float has variable precision.**
To avoid this the work around can be **changing that data type to `float` in pre-copy script.**

```sql
alter table MY_TABLE alter column MY_COLUMN float;
```

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I can change my SQL table to float directly, but I understood it that decimal was always exact, whereas float and double are not as precise. Google seems to confirm this, which is why I used decimal. I would have expected 1.2 to appear as 1.20000000 which is fine, but I don't know where the slight precision error is coming from, because I'm getting values like 1.20000001, even when I import the value as a varchar in which case I would expect it to mirror the oracle exactly